# Query to compare two columns in the same table and update third column based on certain criteria

Tags: sql-server

My requirement is as follows, 
A client can have multiple referrals and each referral will have a Servicestartdateid and ServiceEnddateid. The goal is to populate the CaseopenedDateID with the ServicestartDateId based on the following conditions, (1)if there has been continous ongoing service then pick the earliest servicestartdate and populate the caseopenedDateID, (2)if there is a break in service then pick the earliest reopened date and populate the caseopeneddateid
This should how scenario 1 result set look like

SourceSystemClientID ReferralID  ServiceStartDateID  ServiceEndDateID CaseOpenedDateID

```
8901               R43           20080401          20100628         20080401              
8901               R54           20080627          20090212         20080401              
8901               R66           20090210          20121116         20080401
```

This should how scenario 2 result set look like

SourceSystemClientID ReferralID ServiceStartDateID ServiceEndDateID CaseOpenedDateID

```
12334              R78         20080401         20100628       20080401            
12334              R88         20080627             20090212       20080401            
12334              R98         20090210             20121116       20080401            
12334          R102        20140901         20141201       20140901            
12334          R107        20141001         20141217       20140901
```

Comment: In future, do **not** repost your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've update my query to take in account your update :

```
Select  y.SourceSystemClientID, 
        y.ServiceStartDateID, 
        y.ServiceEndDateID,  
        Res = (select top 1 y2.ServiceStartDateID 
               from yourtable y1
                       inner join yourtable y2
                          ON y1.SourceSystemClientID = y2.SourceSystemClientID 
                             AND y1.ServiceStartDateID <= y2.ServiceEndDateID
               where y.SourceSystemClientID = y1.SourceSystemClientID
                     AND y.ServiceEndDateID = y1.ServiceEndDateID
               order by y2.ServiceStartDateID ) 
from yourtable y
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7992e/24/0) you can use to test the query

Comment: I have run this query on your data and the resultset is this one. What's wrong ?SourceSystemClientID ServiceStartDateID ServiceEndDateID CaseOpenedDateID
8901 20080401 20100628 20090210  
8901 20080627 20090212 20090210  
8901 20090210 20121116 20090210

Comment: Hi Polux, could you please explain, how from yourtable y1 works, I mean if I run only the select top 1 statement individually it throws an error

Comment: Hi Polux, could you please explain the order of execution of the above query?? I am confused with the statement "from yourtable y1" as it has got no select in it

Comment: It's not a select query but an update one to update data your table. If you want the select query, please look at the sqlfiddle I have given you earlier .

Comment: I am sorry, if my question is naive, but can you please explain the order of execution of the part of the code that is  after set caseopenedate =

Comment: Your first question was not very clear and I haven't understood if my query resolve your problem. My query is simple to understand if you know SQL language so it's better you learn it before asking question here.

Comment: :polux, this is giving the wrong result set, in scenario 1 the caseopeneddate should 20080401 in all 3 rows your is only in 2 rows??

Comment: That's because I changed some values to test. Here is a fiddle with yours data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a8da7/1/0

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
;WITH Q2
AS (
    SELECT t.SourceSystemClientID
        ,t.ServiceStartDateID
        ,t.ServiceEndDateID
        ,CASE 
            WHEN t.ServiceStartDateID <= LAG(t.ServiceEndDateID) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY t.SourceSystemClientID ORDER BY t.ServiceStartDateID
                    )
                THEN 0
            ELSE t.ServiceStartDateID
            END CaseOpenedDateID
    FROM your_table t      --replace this with your tablename
    )

SELECT q2.SourceSystemClientID
    ,q2.ServiceStartDateID
    ,q2.ServiceEndDateID
    ,max(q2.CaseOpenedDateID) OVER (
        PARTITION BY q2.SourceSystemClientID ORDER BY q2.ServiceStartDateID
        ) as CaseOpenedDateID
FROM q2
GROUP BY q2.SourceSystemClientID
    ,q2.ServiceStartDateID
    ,q2.ServiceEndDateID
    ,q2.CaseOpenedDateID
```

Comment: This query should take care of that as well. I am using partition by `SourceSystemClientID` so it will break whenever a new client starts. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: What I mean the from clause in your cte, should be dynamic

Comment: Sure...Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: So, instead of providing the values, is there a way it can pick up the data from  the table??

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I will go ahead and update my answer to have you replace it with your table name.

Comment: Nepali Rookie, thanks that definitely works, but I think I didn't explain what I wanted exactly,I am sorry for the confusion. Your query does the comparison on the same row, but I need the comparison done for the servicestartdate to the previous serviceenddate. So for example the servicestartdate in second row should be compared to the serviceend date in 1st row. Is this possible?

Comment: The query should give a result set like this   SourceSystemClientID ServiceStartDateID ServiceEndDateID CaseOpenedDateID
1286 20070726 20070816 20070726
1286 20090205 20110831 20090205
1286 20090604 20100520 20090205
1286 20100126 20100129 20090205
1286 20100611 20100617 20100611
1286 20111122 20130428 20111122
1286 20120112 20120627 20111122
1286 20120118 20130411 20111122
1286 20121113 20130208 20111122

Comment: Absolutely you can! I would use `lag()` function to do so.

Comment: Please see my updated answer which reflects the use of `lag()` function.

Comment: Now, I only get NULL in the case opened date when we us the lag function, could you please copy the result set I have posted in one of the comments to excel spreadsheet, that is what my result set should look like for each client, I am sorry for the hassle for some reason I am not able to attach an image

Comment: No worries...I had to play around with it a little bit. But, try it now and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Nepali rookie, your query works fine, thank you so much, now need to understand how you went about doing that!!! but thanks a lot

Comment: Wonderful! Glad to hear that it worked for you! :)  So, the query is basically divided into two steps. First, you will want to compare your `ServiceStartDateID` with your previous `ServiceEndDateID` and then assign either the `ServiceStartDateID` or 0 depending on the condition above. Next, you just need to assign the max value for `CaseOpenedDateID` in your outer query, which replaces all the 0 values. Hope this helps you understand, let me know if you need further explanation. I would be happy to do so!

Comment: Also, if you liked my answer and thought it was helpful, please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer with an upvote! That would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!  :)

Comment: @user3132672 Do you need any other help?

Comment: I made some changes to the question, could you please help me out??sorry for getting back so late

Comment: I tested above query in SQL fiddle and it returns exactly the same result output that you are expecting. Please see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79068/4/0